# Variable undefined unless wrapped in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I have a empty form and I want to set the "responsible clerk" input to the active user in the mounted lifecycle hook. It looks like this:

```
<b-form-select
     v-model="form.responsible_clerk"
     :options="clerks"
     required
></b-form-select>
```

```
data() {
     return {
          form: {
               responsible_clerk: ""
          }
     }
},
computed: {
      user() {
           return this.$store.getters.getUser;
      }
},
mounted() {
     this.form.responsible_clerk = this.user.name + " " + this.user.lastname;
}
```

This spits out undefined for both `this.form.responsible_clerk` and `this.user`.

When I wrap the content of the mounted hook in a setTimeout with 0ms timeout it works as expected.

```
mounted() {
     setTimeout(() => {
          this.form.responsible_clerk = this.user.name + " " + this.user.lastname;
     },0)
}
```

I needed to do this in several other situations too where I overwrite a variable in the mounted hook.
(E.G. when using vue bootstrap's b-collapse and setting all collapse elements to true on mount and setting the company of a user automatically when creating a user as the admin, also on mount)

Can someone explain to me why this happends, and how one would prevent using setTimeout over and over. It doesnt make sense to me, Vue isnt supposed to work like this.

Edit:
getUser is a vuex getter:

```
getUser(state) {
     return state.user;
}
```

Edit 2:
Just stepped into it again working on sth else:

```
computed: {
    max() {
        return document.getElementById("collapse-header")
            .querySelectorAll('div')
            .length;
    }
}
```

This doesnt work, wrapping it with a setTimeout does...

Comment: What happens in `getUser` getter? Are you making async request in there?

Comment: getUser is a vuex getter:
`getUser(state) { return state.user; }`

Comment: If it was null, I would recieve a console warning and the variable would dynamically change when it recieved its value, I wouldnt mind that. But it doesnt work at all.
`this.form.responsible_clerk = this.user?.name + " " + this.user?.lastname;` doesnt do anything for me too. The variable being null wouldnt be a problem if it just dynamically changed later, but maybe it doesnt dynamically adjust the value of the variable. It only does work with the setTimeout.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually `undefined`, not `""`?

Comment: If the `state.use` is initially NULL and then receives a value - your `responsible_clerk` will not notice that unless you create a watcher and update `responsible_clerk` every time `state.user` changes.

Comment: @connexo They are both `undefined`.

Why wouldnt it not notice the change? Isnt that exactly how computed properties should work? So I need 100 watchers in my application to catch all those situations?

I just checked  @IVOGELOV ist right, but thats extremely time consuming then...

Comment: Never mind, it doesnt notice the change because I only set it in the mounted hook. Still doesnt explain how it doesnt work at all without a setTimeout. It should work once, I dont even need to watch the property, because I only change it once on page load / mount.

Answer (score 0):

Only your `user` is a computed property, and you are only calling to concatenate the user name and lastname in `mounted`. When mounted has been run, it is never called again. Therefore it works when you set a timeout, the user has then had time to be fetched from the store and can be displayed. You can use `watch` to listen to changes in the `user` and then set the value. As your form is an object, we need to listen `deep` and maybe you need to use `immediate` as well. So add a watcher:

```
watch: {
    user: {
        immediate:true,
        deep: true,
        handler(user) {
            this.$set(this.form, 'responsible_clerk', user.name + " " + user.lastname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution. I come across situations like theses all the time. And most of the time its stuff that only needs to happen once. Like getting the username or "isCollapsed" array from the store. Id rather write setTimeout 0 once than write a watcher for every single one of these situations. 
I cant be the only one, shouldnt there be like a "afterMounted" lifecycle hook or sth for these kind of situations, I feel like using setTimeout is a bad way but still more time saving than writing an watcher. Watchers are for variables which change more than once...